# Should there be a badge for people who transfer questions?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

With the design philosophy of using badges to reward desired behavior, shouldn't a badge be created to reward people who transfer questions to the correct site?

Comment: I'm too new on meta to know if this is a feature-request or a discussion. In my mind, it's a bit of both.

Comment: @Daniel: That's okay.  Discussion is implied when tagging something as a feature request.

Answer (score 5):

No, because then people will be closing/moving random threads to get a badge. Always imagine if the site can handle the worst-case behavior. In this case, it cannot, and therefore, shouldn't be a badge.